# Grafana Logs Panel + MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, grafana

What kind of data Grafana Log Panel expects from data source?
Documentation does not say a word about it.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/visualizations/logs-panel/

Gauge / Graph stucture does not work, other fields does not work for me too

```
SELECT
  le.Date as time,
  123 as value,
  'xxx' as metric
FROM [LogEntry] le
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(le.Date)
ORDER BY
  le.Date ASC
```

I expect it to work with something like query below, at least displaying date and text should be trivial.

```
 SELECT
      le.Date as time,
      'anything' as text
    FROM [LogEntry] le
    WHERE
      $__timeFilter(le.Date)
    ORDER BY
      le.Date ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I need to switch "Format as" to "Table".
By default it goes with "Time series" value wich is counter intuitive

[image]